# How to use on click listener on menu items?

Tags: android, android-menu

Instead of using toast , i want to use on click listener in the menu items, and can we use fragments in this case
this is the following code in which i want to add on click, so i can open in a new activity

// Initiating Menu XML file (menu.xml)

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Event Handling for Individual menu item selected
     * Identify single menu item by it's id
     * */
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {

        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
        case R.id.menu_bookmark:
            // Single menu item is selected do something
            // Ex: launching new activity/screen or show alert message
            Toast.makeText(AndroidMenusActivity.this, "Bookmark is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case R.id.menu_save:
            Toast.makeText(AndroidMenusActivity.this, "Save is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case R.id.menu_search:
            Toast.makeText(AndroidMenusActivity.this, "Search is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case R.id.menu_share:
            Toast.makeText(AndroidMenusActivity.this, "Share is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case R.id.menu_delete:
            Toast.makeText(AndroidMenusActivity.this, "Delete is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case R.id.menu_preferences:
            Toast.makeText(AndroidMenusActivity.this, "Preferences is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }    

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start activity in Android 2.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720581/how-to-start-activity-in-android-2-1)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that by simply adding an Intent against each menu item within switch case. Have a look on the below snippet for your reference:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{

    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
    case R.id.menu_bookmark:

        // Ex: launching new activity/screen or show alert message

        Intent intent = new Intent(yourActivity.this, NextActivity.class)
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{

    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
    case R.id.menu_bookmark:

        Intent intent = new Intent(currentactivity.this, toactivity.class)
        startActivity(intent);

        return true;

    case R.id.menu_save:
        Intent intent = new Intent(currentactivity.this, toactivity.class)
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;

    case R.id.menu_search:
        Intent intent = new Intent(currentactivity.this, toactivity.class)
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;

    case R.id.menu_share:
        Intent intent = new Intent(currentactivity.this, toactivity.class)
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;

    case R.id.menu_delete:
        Intent intent = new Intent(currentactivity.this, toactivity.class)
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;

    case R.id.menu_preferences:
        Intent intent = new Intent(currentactivity.this, toactivity.class)
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**Intent**
You have to use intent for moving from one screen to another

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(currentactivity.this,towhichactivityyouwantmove.class) 
    startActivity(intent);
```